# how to find column values of a selected row in a radgrid

Tags: telerik

I am using `RadGrid` with `rowcontextmenu`. When I right click on a RadGrid row and select 'edit option' it will open a popup window.

What I need is when I right click on a Radgrid row, I just want to get the values of 3 columns for that particular selected row.  For example, when I right click on a selected Radgrid row I want to get `Customer name`, `Headend name`, `Site name` values of that selected row.

Here is my code:

```html
<MasterTableView GridLines = "None" DataKeyNames="orderId" CommandItemDisplay="Top"
                            EditMode="EditForms">
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn UniqueName = "ClientSelectColumn" HeaderStyle-Width="3%"
            ItemStyle-Width="3%">
            <HeaderStyle Width = "3%" ></ HeaderStyle >
            <ItemStyle Width="3%"></ItemStyle>
        </telerik:GridClientSelectColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName = "sId" HeaderText="sId" DataField="sId" ReadOnly="true"
            Visible="false">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName = "orderId" HeaderText="orderId" Visible="false"
            ReadOnly="true" DataField="orderId">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName = "Customer Name" HeaderText="Customer Name" DataField="Customer Name"
            ReadOnly="true">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName = "Market Name" HeaderText="Market Name" DataField="Market Name"
            ReadOnly="true">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName = "LOB" HeaderText="LOB" DataField="LOB" ReadOnly="true">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName = "Headend Name" HeaderText="Headend Name" DataField="Headend Name"
            ReadOnly="true">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName = "Project Name" HeaderText="Project Name" DataField="Project Name"
            ReadOnly="true">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName = "Site Name" HeaderText="Site Name" DataField="SiteName"
            ReadOnly="true">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID = "lnkSiteName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval( "Site Name" ) %>'
                    ForeColor="Blue" CommandName="sitename"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName = "Task Status" HeaderText="Task Status" DataField="Task Status"
            ReadOnly="true">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName = "Clarify Account Nbr" HeaderText="Clarify Account Nbr"
            DataField="Clarify Account Nbr">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName = "Site ID" HeaderText="Site ID" DataField="Site ID">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName = "Quote ID" HeaderText="Quote ID" DataField="Quote ID">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn UniqueName = "EDP Created?" HeaderText="EDP Created?" DataField="EDP Created?">
        </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
        <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName = "EditCommandColumn" Display="false">
        </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
    </Columns>
</Mastertableview>
```

```cs
protected void RadMenu1_ItemClick(object sender, RadMenuEventArgs e)
{
    int radGridClickedRowIndex;

    radGridClickedRowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["radGridClickedRowIndex"]);

    switch (e.Item.Text)
    {
        case "Edit Task":
            string OrdID = rg200.MasterTableView.DataKeyValues[radGridClickedRowIndex]["orderId"].ToString();
            lblOrdHeadName.Text = rg200.MasterTableView.NamingContainer.FindControl("Headend Name").ToString();

            Session["orderId"] = OrdID;
            ifrmPopups.Style.Add("height", "409px");
            StringBuilder Script = new StringBuilder();
            Script.Append("document.getElementById('ctl00_PagePlaceholder_WinEditForm_C_ifrmPopups');openpopups()");
            RadAjaxManager1.ResponseScripts.Add(Script.ToString());
            rg200.Rebind();
            break;
    }
}
```

If you see the above code, I am able to get the `orderId` value for that selected column. But when I am trying to get `Headend Name` value I am getting an error. How to get the `Headend Name` value for selected row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```cs
GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)rg200.MasterTableView.Items[radGridClickedRowIndex];

lblOrdHeadName.Text = item["HeadendName"].Text;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following. It worked for me.

```cs
GridDataItem item =(GridDataItem)rg200.MasterTableView.Items[rg200.SelectedItems[0].ItemIndex];

lblOrdHeadName.Text = item["HeadendName"].Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code to get the `Headend Name` value from the right-clicked row:

```
lblOrdHeadName.Text = (rg200.MasterTableView.FindItemByKeyValue("orderId") as GridDataItem)["Headend Name"].Text;
```

Comment: No Problem I found silution....

GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)rg200.MasterTableView.Items[radGridClickedRowIndex];
      lblOrdHeadName.Text = item["HeadendName"].Text;

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to loop through the selected items and store the ID values into an array and thereby pass it to a method. Also set the `EnablePostBackOnRowClick` property of the grid to `true`

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)   
{   
    string[] array = new string[10];   
    int i = 0;   
    if (e.CommandName == "RowClick")   
    {   
        foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.SelectedItems)   
        {   
            array[i] = item.GetDataKeyValue("EmpID").ToString();  // storing to array   
            i++;   
        }   
    }   
}
```